# python argparse hex error

Tags: python, hex, argparse

I'm trying to read some hex values i need for my pythonscript using argparser, an example input looks like:

```
parser.add_argument("start", type=hex, help="hex PC address you want to start recording data")
```

The problem occurs when i try to start the script with a hexvalue.
example:

```
python testscript.py 0x21c
```

Then ik get error:

```
 error: argument start: invalid hex value: '0x21c'
```

is also tried following values: 0X21C, 21C, 21c, 21. All of them result in the same error.

EDIT: i don't nee the hex value converted to a int. I just need the hex value i inputted. Its a PC address where a µC needs to jump to.

Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong here? 
Thanks!

Comment: `hex` takes an integer and turns it into a string.  `argparse` passes a string and stores the transformed result.  What type do you want `args.start` to be?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python argparse fails to parse hex formatting to int type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25513043/python-argparse-fails-to-parse-hex-formatting-to-int-type)

Comment: hex ofcourse, thats why i specified type=hex, if hex takes an integer is doesn't explain why it crashed when i insert 21 and that would give a problem when i want to give 21c as an argument

Comment: @Michvw -- `argparse` will always pass a string to the `type` function (since it's a string on the commandline).  What are you looking to get out of the `hex` function?  You're already passing hex strings from the command-line.  Are you using `hex` to validate the strings?  Or do you expect it to convert the strings `'0x21c` to an integer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inspired by:

[Convert hex string to int in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209513/convert-hex-string-to-int-in-python?rq=1)

I tried

```
In [471]: parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()

In [472]: parser.add_argument('ahex',type=lambda x: hex(int(x,0)))

In [473]: parser.parse_args(['0x21c'])  # valid hex string input
Out[473]: Namespace(ahex='0x21c')

In [474]: parser.parse_args(['21'])  # converts valid int to hex string
Out[474]: Namespace(ahex='0x15')

In [475]: parser.parse_args(['21c'])   # error if string is not valid hex

usage: ipython3 [-h] ahex
ipython3: error: argument ahex: invalid <lambda> value: '21c'
```

As @mgilson stressed in the comments, the `type` parameter is a **function**, one that takes a string and returns something.  It also raises an error if the string is not 'valid'.  `hex()` does not work as `type`, because it takes an integer and returns a hex string. `hex('0x21c')` is not valid use of that function.

For this quick-n-dirty solution I used a `lambda` function.  It could just as well been a `def`.  I used `int(x,0)` to convert the string to a int, in a way that handles both hex strings and integer strings.  Then I converted that integer back to a string using the `hex` function.

So the net effect of my `lambda` is to just validate the hex string.  If a valid string it just returns the same thing (same as if `type` was the default identity `lambda x: x`).

Confusion over the nature of the `type` parameter arises most often when people want a `boolean` value.  `bool()` does not take a string like 'True' or 'False' and return a boolean value.  Look up those SO questions if the issue is still confusing.

Comment: I somehow expected that the argparse library would take care of the conversion. Thank you for this explanation!

Comment: From the Python documentation on `int`: Base 0 means to interpret the string exactly as an integer literal, so that the actual base is 2, 8, 10, or 16.